# Low framerate despite optimization in WebGL

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, webgl

I'm developing a project in WEBGL using Three.Js.

This project consists of a static geometry of room and hundreds of replicated chairs. After putting the whole thing together and using the following techniques to optimize the framerate :

- Instancing for the chairs - each object is loaded once and then instanced and added to the scene in a cycle, with object.clone().
- Octree optimization for object selection raycasting.
- Geometry merge for all the static objects.
- LOD levels for the instanced objects.

I'm still having a terrible performance, of 15fps when all the scene is put together. I'm using two directional lights and a hemisphere light.

After a bit of experimenting, it seems that the bottleneck is in the geometry itself.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the issue ? What would be a reasonable poly count for an acceptable framerate ? Could it be that the geometry i'm using is too heavy ?

For info,

My room geometry has :
    69996 points,
    290571 vertices,
    82607 primitives

and my chair geometry has : 
    1254 points,
    4884 vertices,
    1232 primitives

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll definitely try to profile it and see if I can find any bottleneck. from my analysis until now, I'd think it's fair to say that the bottleneck lies in the geometry, because as I try to render each piece of the scene individually, I get improved framerates, as I add on pieces. Would you say that I could be loading of objects that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: It is certainly possible. But I think rather than me guessing here, it is probably more useful if you profile it and use the webgl inspector first. Then perhaps start another question with the three js tag with the relevant api calls and/or profile results.

Comment: Do you have any stats after the geometry merge? Those hundreds of chairs  should end up being tens after this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the problem lies solely on the poly count of your geometry. I have rendered more at 60 fps. Without code, it is hard to say where the problem is. I think you should profile it first and see if you detect any bottlenecks. Then get the webGL inspector and get a GPU trace. Keep track of the number of times drawXXX is called. That is the more likely bottleneck than poly count.

Finally, it is possible that if you have done every optimization available to Three js, and it is still not fast enough, then it could be a Three js problem. Its no secret that Three js is not written with performance as one of its primary goals. If that is the case, then you are kinda stuck unfortunately.

Comment: OK, so I believe to have found my bottleneck. It seems that my instancing of objects has some issue, that I can't really understand/realize, maybe someone can help me with that. For context, I have a PointCloud with normals, that gives me information about where to position my instanced objects, and also the orientation of the object through the normal quaternion. Then, I loop through this array, and place each instanced object accordingly. After looking at various posts about instancing, merging, etc, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help ?

Comment: I attach the code snippet of the method in question : https://bitbucket.org/snippets/electricganesha/Mdddz

After reviewing it multiple times, I'm really wondering what is wrong here, and why does this method slow down my application from 60fps to 20fps...

Comment: I think it would be to your benefit if you started a new question as you have already accepted this one and thus you will get a limited number of views. I dont have a full grasp of THREE js internals or its API but it seems to be (I could be very wrong here) that you are creating a new mesh object `newObject = preNewObject.clone();` for every vertices in your chair geometry mesh.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it seems that WacławJasper was right, the draw calls were excessive (one for each chair) and that was the bottleneck that made the FPS drop like crazy.

The solution was based on this : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81570/merging-geometry-mesh-without-losing-benefits

By doing a geometry merge, and maintaining the octree for intersection calculation, I managed to replicate the exact same system, while reducing the drawcalls by 90%, which gave a great boost to my FPS rate.

Thanks for all the answers.